# Counting problem- Number of distinct $4$ digit number

Tags: combinatorics

How many distinct $4$-digits distinct Integers one can make from the digits $1$,$3$,$3$,$7$,$7$,$8$ ?

Do we have to enumerate all possibilities for such questions and then go by that?

Case $1$: All unique digits, would give me $4$!
Case $2$: Two identical digits and two unique ..and so on for other cases as well ?

Comment: If you've treated Cases 1 and 2, the only "other cases" would be the two pairs of identical digits, i.e. arranging 3,3,7,7.

Comment: That seems like a very good plan. As @hardmath said, you're not far from finished.

Comment: I feel , Case $1$:All distinct = $4$!=$24$  Case $2$:Two same and two distinct {$3$,$3$,$7$,$7$} = $4$!/($2$! $2$!) = $6$                                                                                        Case $3$:Two same and two other : In this we can have two possibilities, where the other two dash can be any of {$7$,$1$,$8$} or {$3$,$1$,$8$} which is $6$. and then permutation within will give (4!/2!)*3+(4!/2!)*3=72. Total=$6$+$24$+$72$=$102$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twice a $3$ and twice a $7$ gives $\binom{4}{2}=6$ possibilities.

Twice a $3$ and not more than once a $7$ gives $\binom{4}{2}\times3\times2=36$
possibilities.

Twice a $7$ and not more than once a $3$ gives $\binom{4}{2}\times3\times2=36$
possibilities.

All distinct gives (as you said) $4!=24$ possibilities.

Comment: Note that here the order of the numbers matters.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans Do you mean the order of the digits? And is there anything that makes you think that this order should not matter?

Comment: I feel ,                                                                                               Case $1$:All distinct = $4$!=$24$                                                      Case $2$:Two same and two distinct {$3$,$3$,$7$,$7$} = $4$!/($2$! $2$!) = $6$                                                                                        Case $3$:Two same and two other : In this we can have two possibilities, where the other two dash can be any of {$7$,$1$,$8$} or {$3$,$1$,$8$} which is $6$. and then permutation within will give C(3,2)*6+C(3,2)*6=72.Total=$6$+$24$+$72$=$102$

Comment: My mistake. I got a little bit confused.

Comment: @user2016963 My reasoning for twice a $3$ and not more than once a $7$: first choose $2$ (out of $4$) spots for digit $3$. There are $\binom42=6$ possibilities. Then fill up one of the empty spots. This can be done with $1,7$ of $8$ (so $3$ possibilities). Then fill up the second empty spot. If $1$ has been used for the first then this can be done with $7$ or $8$, if $7$ has been used for the first then this can be done with $1$ or $8$,  if $8$ has been used for the first then this can be done with $1$ or $7$. So in all cases $2$ possibilities.

Comment: @drhab: Yes, I also tried that same way, Two $3$ and two out of {7,1,8} + Two $7$ and two out of {3,1,8}=C(3,2)*(4!/2!)+C(3,2)*(4!/2!)=36+36=72. Thanks

Comment: @drhab: do you mind to check this problem please. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312299/12-students-in-a-class-how-many-ways-these-can-take-4-different-tests-if-3-stud#1312318

Answer (score 1):

The number of distinct integers is 102.  Here are two solutions, one short, one long.

For the short solution, the exponential generating function for the number of distinct r-digit permutations of 1,3,3,7,7,8 is
$$f(x) = (1+x)^2 (1+x+ \frac{1}{2!} x^2)^2$$
The coefficient of $x^4$, when $f(x)$ is expanded, is $17/4$; so the coefficient of $\frac{1}{4!}x^4$ is $4! \; (17/4) = 102$.  This is the number of permutations with the required characteristics.

For the long solution, here is the list of integers.

1337
1338
1373
1377
1378
1383
1387
1733
1737
1738
1773
1778
1783
1787
1833
1837
1873
1877
3137
3138
3173
3177
3178
3183
3187
3317
3318
3371
3377
3378
3381
3387
3713
3717
3718
3731
3737
3738
3771
3773
3778
3781
3783
3787
3813
3817
3831
3837
3871
3873
3877
7133
7137
7138
7173
7178
7183
7187
7313
7317
7318
7331
7337
7338
7371
7373
7378
7381
7383
7387
7713
7718
7731
7733
7738
7781
7783
7813
7817
7831
7833
7837
7871
7873
8133
8137
8173
8177
8313
8317
8331
8337
8371
8373
8377
8713
8717
8731
8733
8737
8771
8773

The list was generated by the following Python program:

`import itertools
for x in sorted(set(itertools.permutations([1,3,3,7,7,8], 4))):
    print 1000*x[0] + 100*x[1] + 10*x[2] + x[3]`

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: all are distinct ans:4!=24. 
Case 2: 2 are same and the other 2 are different. Which digit is to be repeated can be decided in 2 ways. The other 2 digits can be selected in 3 ways. The selected digits can be arranged in 12 ways. Total ways in this case=2×3×12=72. 
Case 3: 4 digit number formed by 3,3,7,7
Number of ways : 6.
ANS:24+72+6=102